# Does Octopus deploy support ADFS/SAML integration?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I've seen that Octopus Supports LDAP integration.
But does it support SAML 2.0 or ADFS integration?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your stuck with windows or forms based authentication.

> If you are using Active Directory Authentication with Octopus, there
>   are two ways to sign in.
>
> Integrated authentication Forms-based

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/3048127

ADFS would require changes to server side code which isn't open source.

The `Octopus Server` -> `Tentacle` communication uses [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). Perhaps you can alter your design to keep the Octopus Server somewhere accessible and an Octopus Tentacle in the ADFS environment.

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Octopus+-+Tentacle+communication